# live site do not update after importing sql database

Tags: database, mysql

My live
 website is not updating after  importing sql database from wamp local server
until last time all went perfect but last night I was not able to see the changes live made in local.
what I did:
- worked in local creating page and uploading a new contat php page and a contact template
- made some change in the front end (style)
- Exported database in sql format
- changed links in sql (local to live )
- Imported in live mysql database
- updated the stylesheet with the changes and also uploaded the new contact form to live via ftp

nothing happened. Only the style changes took effect
I did not see any new menu added and not any new pages that i created.
The contact form is not present, and also the new template I created for the form. Pratically, the DB Sql Live didn't change.

I have wordpress 4.2  updated yesterday in live website

P.s. I disabled also the cache in wp config to try to solve but Nothing changed
Thanks in advance :)

paolo

Comment: What exactly are you missing? Your pages? Your templates?

Comment: thanks, I added this also in the post: I did not see any new menu added and not any new pages that i created. E.g. the contact form is not present, and also the new template I created for the form. Pratically, the DB Sql Live didn't change

Answer (score 0):

I had something similar, entries of some post types didnt show.

If your posts have the same IDs between dev/live environment, get the edit URL and replace the ID to see if it loads. Like :

```
http://yoursite.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=23&action=edit
```

Replace the ID (here '23') by the ID of the post/page/anythingelse you cannot see in live.

If this solves your problem, that could mean a strange bug in the Wordpress update...

Comment: Hi, Sebastien. They have the same id (the last part, obviously)

Comment: HI all. I solved the issue deleting a wordfence table  
  wp_wfFileMods   link  that can help, (i saw that is not a uncommon issue) : https://wordpress.org/support/topic/remove-wf-from-database?replies=22

Answer (score 0):

This was an issue I was dealing with while changing from a MacAir to a MacPro. 
I definitely recommend utilizing WP All In One Migrator & then installing the free extension for it to increase import space. Save it as a file, import it on the new site. Piece of cake, if you encounter any errors I would just email the devs of the app for some free advice there too